# What is the Impact of TRACE Method?

Tags: web-application, appsec, exploit, http

What attacker will benefit of TRACE Exploitation and What is the Recommendation to fix this issue?

Comment: Duplicated: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56955/is-the-http-trace-method-a-security-vulnerability, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7703/implications-of-trace-track-methods-on-apache, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16676/http-trace-vulnerability-discovered-what-should-i-do

Comment: Please refrain from asking anymore questions as long as  you have not read our FaQ and help pages.

Answer (score 1):

Anything sent in a request using the HTTP TRACE method will be echo-ed back in the response.

This may lead to [Cross Site Tracing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Tracing) (XST) attacks, which could lead to steal a user's cookie even if the cookie has the HTTPOnly attribute flag set.

The HTTP TRACE method is used for debugging purposes only and should be disabled.

Apache Configuration:

```
TraceEnable off
```

IIS Registry Setting:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters
EnableTraceMethod: 0
```